# Confused... why?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, letters

> Finish of bronze or finish of gold.
>   Uncurse my bluff and the way will be told.
>   In fiction and fact, at the edge of the grave.
>   I'll fit in a tux if I see where you pave.
>   I'm a dragon's start—a circus split up.
>   I'm a term's first part—to pass, sum it up!

Confused... why?  
What am I?

---

Hint 1:

> The answer is not one thing, but a group. Including the title, there are 13 different members of this group hinted at through various methods.

Hint 2:

> Word/letter play are key, and the title is somewhat Cryptic

Hint 3:

> The riddle is cluing in on many examples in lieu of directly defining the answer

Edits:  Hints added, as well as a tag.  Very slight rewording of the riddle to perhaps be clearer.

Comment: "In fiction and fact, at the edge of the grave." I think this is referring to the letter C before (at the edge) the letter T (which resembles a cross at a grave.

Comment: "Finish of bronze" may refer the letter C to (3rd letter)

Comment: You're right to be looking at the letters in some of the words, but these first guesses are not the right track. I'll add a hint in a few hours

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope this is on the right track:

> Postal service standard [suffix abbreviations](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm)

Finish of bronze or finish of gold.

> Bronze is 3rd → RD (road) and gold is 1st → ST (street)

Uncurse my bluff and the way will be told.

> bluff - fu → BLF (bluff) and WAY (way)

In fiction and fact, at the edge of the grave.

> In fi*ct*ion and fa*ct* → CT (court) and edge of grave → AVE (avenue)

I'll fit in a tux if I see where you pave.

> OP addressed: if I see where you pave implies view → VW (view) fits nicely in tux (tuVWx)
>
>  original try: a tux is a jacket with jct  fit inside giving JCT (junction)

I'm a dragon's start — a circus split up.

> *dr*agon's start → DR (drive) and *cir*cus split → CIR (circle)

I'm a term's first part — to pass, sum it up!

> *ter*m's first part → TER (terrace) and PASS (pass) and, from OP, sum it → SMT (summit)

Title: Confused… why?

> HWY (highway)

Comment: This is correct! You only missed one clue, which was the toughest rot13("vs V frr jurer lbh cnir" vzcyvrf gur fgerrg fhssvpr 'ivrj' jubfr nooerivngvba 'IJ' svgf avpryl va 'GHK' (GHIJK))

Comment: Oh, and rot13(Fhz vg  = fhzzvg, nabgure fhssvk) but that was just for fun.  Excellent solve!

Comment: That was a top last clue which I thought was to write up the connections - I was misdirected! I wouldn't have got the tux clue - neat wordplay :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of a stretch, but I really want to say this is

> Organization XIII from Kingdom Hearts

Finish of bronze

> Laxaeus, The Taciturn Stalwart. I have no idea why though.

Finish of gold

> Xemnas? Since he's the boss, he's the gold medal, the number one. I'm really stretching here.

Uncurse my bluff

> This refers to Luxord, also known as the Gambler of Fate. Bluffing is related to gambling.

The way will be told

> Maybe Larxene? She tells Sora about how he forgot Namine, which leads him deeper into Castle Oblivion.

In fiction and fact

> This refers to Zexion, the Cloaked Schemer, known for his powers of illusion.

At the edge of the grave

> Axel? He sort of dies helping Sora rescue Kairi, except he's not quite dead.

I'll fit in a tux

> Demyx, possibly. Also known as The Melodious Nocturne

If I see where you pave

> I believe this is referring to Xigbar, the Freeshooter. If you get in his line of sight (or if he sees where you step/pave), he'll shoot you with his sniper rifle.

I'm a dragon part

> I believe this is referring to Xigbar, also known as the the Whirlwind Lancer. He controls Dragoons

A circus split up

> Saix, The Luna Diviner

I'm at the term's start

> Marluxia, also known as The Graceful Assassin. He shows Sora into Castle Oblivion, hence the first Organization member ever introduced.

To pass, sum it up!

> This may be a stretch, but is this Vexen, The Chilly Academic?

Confused... why?

> I'm pretty sure you are referring to Roxas here. At the beginning of the game, he doesn't know who he truly is. Even later, when he merges with Sora, everyone in the Organization refers to him as Roxas, confusing Sora.

Hint

> There are thirteen members of the Organization that makes up their name

Comment: Sorry, this isn't it. While a small amount of outside knowledge is necessary to solve, it's not about any particular piece of media.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete solution, but some thoughts and guesses.

> Possible solution: equivocation. Or maybe a crossover or intersection. 
>  It seems to me that every sentence has at least to meanings.

Finish of bronze or finish of gold.

> First and third place in a race. The surface treatment of metal objects. For example a bronze or gold medal.

Uncurse my bluff and the way will be told.

> Bluff could mean cliff or misdirection. Maybe the direction of a traveling route or the way hot this puzzle should be solved.

In fiction and fact, at the edge of the grave.

> Might refer to an imaginary part of the riddle (e. g. dragons) and the obvious meaning.

I'll fit in a tux if I see where you pave.

> pave, pavement, guiding a way...

I'm a dragon part—a circus split up.

> split up could refer to two different meanings.

I'm at the term's start—to pass, sum it up!

> Passing through. Passing the exam/puzzle.

Confused... why?

> Going astray, getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling this is about hiking. Something like rock, stone, mountain, sign, guide.

Finish line or sign on top of a mountain.
A sign with gold or bronze finish.

Bluff meaning a cliff. A way meaning a hiking trail.

At the edge of the grave is a tomb stone which is also somewhat of a sign.

Tux prealps. Or tuxedo.

The offshoot of a mountain is like the tail of a dragon.

All the hints shoulds lead to a hypernym that I am not aware of.

Maybe landmark? Or the 14 biggest mountains (over 8.000)

Comment: Not about hiking, sorry